# Custom CSS with Checkbox and NgFor

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I am trying to get a custom check box 'clickable' when being iterated on with an `*ngFor`. I have the custom CSS, but nothing is working on the click event.

I am guessing that it is because of the `for` property on the label, but I don't know how to fix it.

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4znmwv?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.css&view=editor

HTML:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of data">
  <input type="checkbox" [checked]= "item.selected" (change)="setChange(item, $event)">
  <label htmlFor="{{item.name}}">{{item.name}}</label>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
input[type="checkbox"] {
  position: absolute;
  height: 1px;
  width: 1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  clip: rect(1px 1px 1px 1px); /* IE6, IE7 */
  clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px);
}


input[type="checkbox"] + label {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 1.5rem;
}


input[type="checkbox"] + label::before {
  content: '';
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  color: #2a3037;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-color: #1c8d3e;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label::before {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #138630;
  border-color: #000000;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px;
  left: 27px;
  border-left: 2px solid black;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  height: 6px;
  width: 13px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

input[type="checkbox"]:focus + label::before {
  outline: #5d9dd5 solid 1px;
  box-shadow: 0 0px 8px #5e9ed6;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:disabled + label {
  color: #575757;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:disabled + label::before {
  background: #ddb862;
}
```

Comment: `labels` use the attribute `for` not `htmlFor`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this , I have just set the for attribute for the label base of the checkbox id that have been set by item name

```
<div *ngFor="let item of data">
  <input type="checkbox"  [id]="item.name">
  <label [for]="item.name">{{item.name}}</label>
</div>
```

[**demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tugjru)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div *ngFor="let item of data;let i = index">
  <input type="checkbox" [checked]= "item.selected" id="{{item.name}}" (change)="setChange(item, $event)">
  <label for="{{item.name}}">{{item.name}}</label>
</div>
```

Try this.

Set the id as the same as the for of the label it will work properly and `for` is only the attribute name for label and not htmlFor.

Here i have added index for reference if you want the id to be different from the  itemname which is dynamically gives index Use like this

```
<div *ngFor="let item of data;let i = index">
  <input type="checkbox" [checked]= "item.selected" id="{{'checkbox'+i}}" (change)="setChange(item, $event)">
  <label for="{{'checkbox' + i}}">{{item.name}}</label>
</div>
```

This way your id would be something like this

checkbox1

checkbox2

...